# There does not seem to be a good substitute for core.exportVariable in github-script right now

Tags: github, github-actions, github-script

Every time we use `core.exportVariable` which, as far as I know, [is the canonical way to export a variable](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/core#exporting-variables) in `@action/core` and, consequently, in `github-script`, you get an error such as this one:

> Warning: The `set-env` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/

That [link](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/) leads to an explanation of *environment files*, which, well, are files. Problem is files do not seem to have such a great support in `github-script`. There's the [`@actions/io` package](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/io), but there's no way to create a file with that.

So is there something I'm missing, or there is effectively no way to create an environment file form inside a `github-script` step?

Answer (score 1):

You no longer need the [`actions/github-script`](https://github.com/actions/github-script) nor any other special API to export an environment variable. According to the [Environment Files](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files) documentation, you can simply write to the `$GITHUB_ENV` file directly from the workflow step like this:

```
steps:
  - name: Set environment variable
    run: echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

The step will expose given environment variable to subsequent steps in the currently executing workflow job.

Comment: Except, as I say above, if the environment variable is generated from within a github-script step, there's actually no way to export it or to write it to a file.